# Shedule Cloud Notification in Flutter And Dart

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, notifications

I have created todo app but i want to implement shedule notification init but the notification should be based on date and time and it will be from cloud .. does any one have nay idea how to code it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-schedule-local-notification-using-timezone/) will help you to achieve this `functionality` or create some idea for that

In another case, you can schedule notifications in firebase with firebase messaging:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0
```

Comment: actully i want to create a shedule notification in my application but it should take date and time from my 
 cloud database and send notification and it all will hapeen on client side